# Can I cause gnu make to write warnings to stdout instead of stderr?

Tags: tfsbuild, gnu-make

I am launching a build from Microsoft Team Foundation Server, which has an option to fail the build if anything writes to stderr.  `make` writes warnings to stderr, which fails the build even if it was actually successful.

I have browsed the output of `make --help` but did not find anything to this effect:  Is there I way that I can prevent compiler warnings from being written to stderr, but still let make fail the build by writing other sorts of things to stderr?

Answer (score 2):

It's not part of GNU make because on GNU, you can run make as

```
make 2>&1
```

and obtain the desired effect: The `2>&1` directive simply redirects standard error (2) to standard output (1).  Whether that works with TFS depends on how it invokes GNU make.  You may have to add an explicit invocation of bash if the default shell does not support such redirects, like this:

```
bash -c "make 2>&1"
```

Comment: I imagine that there are other things that could go wrong--besides warnings--that might get written to stderr, and I'd still like them too go to stderr so that the build fails and it gets my attention.  If nothing like that shows up, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Anything that causes an error should cause make to terminate with a non-zero exit status, so that should already be covered.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I've got a build that is "failing" because make wrote a compiler warning to stderr. The message I get from TFS is `make exited with code 0` but it treats this like a failure because stderr was touched.

Comment: make doesn't write compiler warnings, to anywhere.  Compilers write compiler warnings.  If the compiler writes the warning to stderr, there's nothing make can do about that: that's up to the compiler.  No make options can change the compiler's mind about where to write warnings.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to trap *make*'s stderr, but not the stderr of any program that *make* runs in a recipe?

This will work in a decent gnu environment (e.g., cygwin).

1. Point *make*'s descriptor 3 at its current stderr
2. Redirect *make*'s stderr to its stdout
3. Replace the shell used by recipes with a script that redirects the recipe's stderr to the recipe's descriptor 3 (i.e., *make*'s original stderr)

Proof of concept:

```
.PHONY: t
t:
    $(warning We want this to go to make's stdout)
    echo "We want this to go to make's stderr" >&2
```

Replacement shell (in file `SH` say):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>&3
exec bash -"$@"
```

Invocation:

```
$ make SHELL=./SH 3>&2 2>&1
```

To see what is happening, collect fds 1, 2 and 3 in files, and then look at the files.

```
$ (make SHELL=./SH 3>&2 2>&1) 1>1 2>2 3>3
$ head 1 2 3
==> 1 <==
Makefile:3: We want this to go to make's stdout
echo "We want this to go to make's stderr" >&2

==> 2 <==
We want this to go to make's stderr

==> 3 <==
```

So, `$(warning …)` went to stdout, and any recipe's stderr still went to stderr. Sheesh.